# Plot mouse clicks over an image

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I writing a code in Python 3 to plot some markers over a DICOM image. for this, I wrote a very short program:

In the main program, I read the DICOM filename from the terminal and plot the image.

main_prog.py:

```
import sys
import dicom as dcm
import numpy as np
from   matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from   dicomplot import dicomplot as dcmplot

filename  = sys.argv[1]
dicomfile = dcm.read_file(filename)
dicomimg  = dicomfile.pixel_array

fig = plt.figure(dpi = 300)
ax  = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.set_cmap(plt.gray())
plt.pcolormesh(np.flipud(dicomimg))
dcm  = dcmplot(ax)

plt.show()
```

Then, I define a class to store the coordinates clicked by the user and plot each of them at a time over the image:

dicomplot.py

```
from   matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class dicomplot():
    def __init__(self, img):
        self.img    = img
        self.fig    = plt.figure(dpi = 300)
        self.xcoord = list()
        self.ycoord = list()
        self.cid    = img.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self)

    def __call__(self, event):
        if event.button == 1:
            self.xcoord.append(event.x)
            self.ycoord.append(event.y)
            self.img.plot(self.ycoord, self.xcoord, 'r*')
            self.img.figure.canvas.draw()
        elif event.button == 2:
            self.img.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cid)
        elif event.button == 3:
            self.xcoord.append(-1)
            self.ycoord.append(-1)
```

The problem is that when I click over the image, the markers appear in a different scale, and not over the image as they are supposed to.

How can I modify my code so when I click on the image, all the mouse clicks are stored and ploted in the desired position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MouseEvent` objects carry both a `x`/`y` and`xdata`/`ydata` attributes ([docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.MouseEvent.ydata)).  The first set is in screen coordinates (ex pixels from the lower left) and the second set (`*data`) are in the data coordinates.

You might also be interested in [`mpldatacursor`](https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor).